# Return Multiple Parameters in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

Let's assume that we have a function in Node.js, what is the proper way to get returned both parameters?

For example i have a function which returns an encrypted message just like the above code and i want to return also and the Hmac hash which it will be reproduced. Can i return both values from one function?

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
exports.AesEncryption = function(Plaintext, SecurePassword) {
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-ecb', SecurePassword);
    var encrypted = cipher.update(Plaintext, 'utf-8', 'base64');
    encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
    return encrypted;
};
```

Comment: You mean other than an array or an object??

Comment: Just put them in an object or array.

Answer (score 3):

You could return two values by just using an array:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
exports.AesEncryption = function(Plaintext, SecurePassword) {
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-ecb', SecurePassword);
    var encrypted = cipher.update(Plaintext, 'utf-8', 'base64');
    encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
    return [encrypted, cipher];
};
```

Or an object (preferred):

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
exports.AesEncryption = function(Plaintext, SecurePassword) {
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-ecb', SecurePassword);
    var encrypted = cipher.update(Plaintext, 'utf-8', 'base64');
    encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
    return {encrypted: encrypted, cipher: cipher};
};
```

Comment: Technically, list/dictionary doesn't refer to JS. Array and Object are the terms here

Comment: @SterlingArcher Fair enough. :) I will switch the terminology.